# Google Cloud Bigtable Update or Insert with Versioning

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm wondering if I should use a `update` query to update my row data or use `maxversions` and enable the versioning and just insert.

I do understand it may depend on what kind of data I need to store, but just wanted to know if there is a performance difference between querying (selecting) a data witch has versioning or non-versioning. Or has a performance difference between `insert` and `update`.

Comment: What do you mean by insert?  Would you set an explicit version on every cell that write to Cloud Bigtable?

Comment: By putting a row in the table with out any versions. Just like the one [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/master/java/hello-world/src/main/java/com/example/cloud/bigtable/helloworld/HelloWorld.java#L98)!

Comment: Putting a row without an explicit version means use "now()" as the time.

Answer (score 3):

Performance is impacted by the size of the row and the amount of data returned from the server.

Bigtable has to read an entire row for every request.  That will be a limiting factor on reads.  At some size (100s+ of MB), systemic performance will degrade any time the tablet with that row is loaded.  When the row size reaches GBs, you'll have major problems.

At query time, performance is also impacted by how much data is returned from the server.  You can still get decent performance lower range of "large rows" if you limit your `Get` or `Scan` to a small subset of the row.  Limits like cells per row, and/or retrieving only a few qualifiers would help with the network costs.

In general, it's better to keep your rows smaller, if you can.  That is generally done with a combination of "insert" and some sort of age/version restriction on the column family.

Comment: So whether the data has multiple versions or not, the performance of getting the data is depended by the size. Which means if I don't need any history of the data (versions) I should just update the target row. Am I right?

Comment: not using an explicit timestamp will mean that you're defaulting to creating new cells each time.  Generally, that will work, assuming that you have GC Rules.  You can also always explicitly choose a consistent timestamp which will also be efficient.

Comment: @SolomonDuskis Is the statement "Bigtable has to read an entire row for every request." still true? In a different SO question/answer, you mentioned that GCP Cloud Bigtable has all column families in a single locality group; so I'm wondering when we only fetch a subset of column families from a bigtable, the bigtable host still needs to read an entire row (all column families) before returning to me what I want. This will help us design bigtable schema.

Comment: Bigtable (the internal, non-cloud version) could read column families from different locality groups. At this point, the Cloud Bigtable product does not provide the ability to create locality groups, so all of the row will be read at once.

Comment: @SolomonDuskis Thanks for the answer! My team was wondering exactly about that (one of the differences between the internal one and Cloud bigtable).